# Change URL in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress site.

Ive tried to change the URL in the htaccess.

i need to change the post type like :-

```
http://www.ccc.com/?post_type=service
```

to

```
http://www.ccc.com/service
```

What can I do?

Comment: Do you want to make a custom post type archive? Have you seen this? http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen Why do you want to solve it by modifying htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Admin Panel` > `Settings` > `Permalinks` > Select 5th item i.e  > `Post name`.

This will return you `http://www.ccc.com/your_page_slug`.

[image: See attachments]

Comment: i will try this way but it still like http://www.psyc.org.sa/ar/?post_type=service

Answer (score 0):

Inside your WordPress dashboard, go to Settings > Permalinks.
You'll want to make sure you have access to modifying the .htaccess file.

Comment: i will try this way but it still like http://www.psyc.org.sa/ar/?post_type=service

Comment: Are you creating custom post types? Have you checked http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types ? What's your code look like?